# How to save a imageview as binary data in Swift 5

Tags: core-data, uiimageview, uiimage, binary-data, swift5

I am trying to save the imageview to core data as a binary data. In my function I have already saved a string and it works perfectly. However when I try to do the exact same thing with (theTitle2) it does not work. I also have class cdhandler in my question below which is what is saved in app deleagate.I think what I have to do is somehow convert the image view to a uiimage then save it.

```
        func enterData() {
let appDeldeaget = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDeldeaget.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)
let theTitle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
theTitle.setValue(enter.text, forKey: "userName")
let theTitle2 = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
theTitle2.setValue(imageV.image, forKey: "pit")

do {

    try context.save()
    itemName.append(theTitle)


}
catch {  }
//


    }
```

APP DELEGATE

```
     class cdHandler: NSObject {
class func saveObject(userName: String) -> Bool {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)

    let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    managedObject.setValue(userName, forKey: "userName")
    managedObject.setValue(userName, forKey: "pit")

    do {
        try context.save()
        return true

    } catch {
        return false

    }
}
}
```

**pic of Core Data**
[image]

Comment: Saving image as binary in database is a very fast way to deplete memory. Instead you should write it to disk and save the path's reference with core data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save image in core data, convert image to data then store it. Like

```
let data = imageV.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) //image in JPEG format
or
let data = imageV.image?.pngData() // image in PNG format

theTitle2.setValue(data, forKey: "pit")
```

Comment: I am still getting a runtime error at **    let theTitle2 = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)** stating Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-07-30 22:56:16.431284-0400 ramitSethi[2668:271665] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value